# Prove that $\left(\forall\ a \in A \right)\ aTe = eTa = e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $\left(A,\ *, T\right)$ be a Ring and $e$ be its identity element.

Is it possible to prove the following statement without using the regularity of $aTe$ in the underlying group $\left(A,\ *\right)$?

$$\left(\forall\ a \in A \right)\ aTe = eTa = e$$

**Proof using regularity:**

$$aTe = a T \left(e * e \right)$$

$$\Leftrightarrow aTe = \left(a T e \right)* \left(a T e \right)$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \left(aTe\right)*e = \left(a T e \right)* \left(a T e \right)$$

Since $aTe \in A$ and $\left(\forall\ x \in A \right)\ x$ is regular in $\left(A,\ *\right)$, then $e = \left(a T e \right)$

The same way, we can prove $eTa = e$

I appreciate any hints!

Comment: What is $T$?  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! $*$ and $T$ are both operations on $A$.

Comment: You are more than welcome.  My question is, *what* operation is $T$?  I assume $*$ satisfies the axioms for what is usually termed "multiplication" . . .

Comment: What strange notation! Is $e$ the zero element of the ring? So in more standard notation, are you asking for a proof that $0 \times a = a \times 0 = 0$?

Comment: @RobertLewis It looks to me as though $*$ is addition, $T$ is multiplication, and $e$ is the zero element.

Comment: @RobertLewis $T$ is associative and distributive over the abelian group operation $*$.

Comment: OK, unique notation!  It appears to me that $*$ corresponds to what is usually written "$+$", and $T$ to "$\cdot$".  Am I right?

Comment: @RobertLewis If you are talking about the usual addition $+$ and multiplication $\cdot$, then you're not right. Otherwise yes. In abstract algebra, we use in general abstract notations. You can use your favourite ones just stay consistent with the global rules.

Comment: @AyoubFalah:  Thank you for your input, I'll remember that!

Comment: @RobertLewis You´re most welcome!

Comment: @DerekHolt Choose your favourite notations! How would you prove $0 \times a = a \times 0 = 0$ without using the regularity of $0$ in $\left(A,\ +\right)$

Comment: That's standard Lemma 1 in Ring Theory. $a\times 0 = a \times (0+0) = (a \times 0) + (a \times0) $, so $a \times 0 = 0$ by the cancellation law in groups.

Comment: Thank you for that! In my question stand _without using the regularity_. That means _without using the cancellation law in groups_.

Comment: In that case just prove the cancellation law in groups. Then you can use it.